# Разные правила для разных URLов в .htaccess

Tags: url, .htaccess, wordpress

Как написать для урл со следующими ссылками:

домен.ru/blog/
домен.ru/board/
домен.ru/forum/

Правило: вместо .htm заканчивать ссылку без расширения .htm (пример: домен.ru/blog/302513).

А для всех остальных ссылок правило для назначения ссылок в виде названия записи для WP:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Проблема возникла из-за старого архива сайта на .htm и нового на уже на wp.
Весь старый сайт залит из архива, и необходимо сохранить URL старых и совместить с настроенными на WP.

Comment: @4upik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, как-то так:

```
   RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)\.htm /blog/$1 [R,L] # преобразовали на ссылку без htm и переправили на нее
    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) - [L] # если открываем из папки blog, то ничего не делать
    RewriteRule ^board/(.*)\.htm /board/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^board/(.*) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)\.htm /forum/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^forum/(.*) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```